# React SVG Rendering Optimization

Tags: reactjs, svg, d3.js, react-simple-maps

I made a [globe map](https://gaushao.gitlab.io/react-simple-map-globe/) with [react-simple-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-maps), did my best to optimize the rendering but still slow with complex json.

steps to reproduce

1. drag/zoom the globe, check performance
2. change top radio input to regions (more complex json)
3. drag/zoom the globe (if you can)

how to avoid 'out of screen rendering'?

is there anyway to improve rendering performance while dragging the globe?

my last try:

```
export function useCameraCenterDistance() {
  const {
    center: [x, y],
  } = useCameraContext()
  return useCallback(
    (point: Coord) => {
      const distance = getDistance([x, y], point)
      return reflect(distance, 180)
    },
    [x, y]
  )
}
```

Comment: i've changed map data to lighter geojson, but still not able to avoid 'out of screen rendering'

Comment: got some optimization progress from react dispatches and choosing a lighter topojson,. but Mongolia still missing https://gitlab.com/gaushao/react-simple-map-globe/-/issues/2#note_694161455